# Grails integration testing facebook graph plugin

Tags: grails, facebook-graph-api, integration-testing, grails-controller

I'm using http://www.grails.org/plugin/facebook-graph to get user profile, but I'm stuck to test from controllers. Anybody could advice me how to mock or test facebook session in integration testing?

Answer (score 0):

how about start testing some post in your wall, using the follow code:

```
facebookGraphService.publishWall(message:"The message",
           link:"http://www.example.com/article.html",
           name:"The name of the link")
```

Comment: Oh sorry, I mean integration testing.

Comment: I see... I will try something here, and let u know soon!

Comment: @toy why dont you just inject the service in your integration test class, and call the services methods?! have you tried that?!